# Why $Sha(E_n/\mathbb{Q})[2] = 0 \implies Sha(E_n/\mathbb{Q})[2^\infty] = 0$ holds?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $A$ be an Abelian group. Define $A[2^n] = \{a \in A \mid 2^na = 0\}$ for a positive integer $n$.

Then, let $A[2^\infty] = \bigcup_{n\geq 1} A[2^n]$.

In general, $A[2]=0 \nRightarrow A[2^\infty]=0$.

However, this paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.4393v2.pdf), which deals with the case where $A$ is the Tate-Shafarevich group $Sha(E_n/\mathbb{Q})$ of an elliptic curve $E_n: y^2 = x^3 - n^2x$, states in the proof of example $G$ that
$Sha(E_n/\mathbb{Q})[2] = 0 \implies Sha(E_n/\mathbb{Q})[2^\infty] = 0$.

Why does the implication hold in this specific case, or have I misunderstood some fundamental fact about Abelian groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a \in A[2^\infty]\backslash\{0\}$, then  $a \in A[2^n]$ for some  $n \ge 1$. So $2^na=0$; in particular, $a'=2^{n-1}a$ is such that $a' \neq 0$ and $2a'=0$ (if $2^{n-1}a=0$, just replace $n-1$ for $n-2$ and so on).

Comment: Do you claim $A[2]\implies A[2^∞]=0$ for general abelian group ?

Comment: I guess you mean $A[2]=0\Rightarrow A[2^\infty]=0$, and yes, that is what he argues above.

Comment: Yes, by contraposition. Another way of to see this:  If $a \in A[2^n]$ is nonzero, then $a$ has order equals to a power of $2$. So the subgroup $\langle a \rangle$ has order divisible by $2$, and it contains an element of order $2$ (Cauchy's Theorem).